# Is this always true for double integrals?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Solving a problem of double integral, the next equality i use for solve the problem, the point is, this always is true:

$$\int_a^b \int_{f(x)}^{g(x)}h(x,y) \,dy\,dx=\int_a^b \int_c^{g(x)} h(x,y) \,dy\,dx - \int_a^b \int_c^{f(x)}h(x,y) \,dy\,dx$$

For proof that, we just use the property of the integral in one dimention:
$$\int_a^b \int_{f(x)}^{g(x)}h(x,y) \,dy\,dx = \int_a^b \left[ \int_c^{g(x)} h(x,y) \,dy\,dx - \int_c^{f(x)}h(x,y) \, dy \right] \, dx$$.
This property is not very useful, but i wanna know if is true always.
Sorry for my english.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to quote? $$\int_{a}^b \int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} h(x,y) \ dy \ dx = \int_{a}^b \left( \int_{c}^{g(x)} h(x,y) \ dy - \int_c^{f(x)} h(x,y) \ dy \right) \ dx $$

Comment: @FaraadArmwood yes, i don't know is that equality is correct or wrong? in case this equality is correct, i can apply always?

Comment: @julip godoy You are correct that it follows from the case when you are integrating a single variable function.

Comment: It is correct whenever the right-hand side is defined.  In theory it is possible for $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ to be close together whereas $h(x,y)$ has a singularity between $c$ and $g(x)$ making the integrals on the RHS divergent.  But this is true for the one-dimensional form as well.  Since you already have a proof, why do you need confirmation that it's true?

Comment: @ErickWong thanks a lot, what is RHS divergent?

Comment: thanks a lot @FaraadArmwood

Comment: @juliogodoy RHS == Right Hand Side

Comment: @ErickWong thanks again